# How to return streambuf pointer

Tags: c++, streambuf

I have wrote my own input streambuf, which should work with gzipped files.
Here is its interface:

```
class gzstreambuf : public std::streambuf
{
    static const int bufferSize = 8192;

public:
    gzstreambuf();
    ~gzstreambuf();
    int is_open() { return opened_; }
    gzstreambuf* open(const std::string& name, int mode);
    std::streampos pubseekpos(std::streampos offset, std::ios_base::openmode which = std::ios_base::in);
    int underflow();

private:
    void close();

private:
    gzFile            file;
    char              opened;
    char              buffer[bufferSize];
    int               mode;
    std::string       fileName;
};
```

I am trying to write function which will take the file name and return ordinary streambuf in case if file is non gzipped ,and gzstreambuf otherwise:

```
boost::shared_ptr<std::streambuf>
getStreamBuffer(const std::string& fileName)
{
    const bool isGzippedFile = ( fileName.size() >= 3 && ".gz" == fileName.substr(fileName.size() -3));
    std::ifstream is(fileName.c_str());
    boost::shared_ptr<std::streambuf> strBuf;

    if(! isGzippedFile)
    {
        strBuf.reset(is.rdbuf());
    }
    else
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<gzstreambuf> gz(new gzstreambuf);
        gz->open(fileName, std::ios_base::in);
        strBuf = gz;
    }

    return strBuf;
}
```

But this implementation will not work in case of non gzipped files, because `is` object  will be destroyed after call of this function.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It is not clear what your actual question is. What concrete problems do you have writign your function?

Comment: you can have only one return type - so return a pointer to the base class.

Answer (score 3):

You have two major problems with the `getStreamBuffer` function, even though both are really the same and both leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

1. Your use of `std::auto_ptr`. You then use this smart pointer to get the raw pointer contained in the smart pointer, just to put in *another* smart pointer. However, the problem is that once the `std::auto_ptr` object goes out of scope, the contained pointer will be deleted, so the other smart pointer will now point to a deleted object.
2. The second problem is the same as the previous, but with the returned smart pointer. You get the raw pointer from `strBuf` and return that. However, since `strBuf` is not really *shared* and its reference counter is one, the pointer will be deleted once `strBuf` goes out of scope, making the returned pointer be a pointer to a now deleted object.

The first problem can be solved by not using `std::auto_ptr` at all, or using e.g. `std::shared_ptr` and use simple assignment to `strBuf`.

The second problem can be solved by simply returning `strBuf`.